# Entity framework хранимая процедура без выходных параметров

Tags: c#, entity-framework, исключения

Сделал импорт хранимой процедуры. При вызове вылетает внутреннее исключение.

> {"При выполнении определения команды
> произошла ошибка. Подробные сведения
> см. во внутреннем исключении."}
> {"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code
> = -84\r\nprocedure COPY_SETTINGS does not return any values\r\nAt line 1,
> column 10"}

Но по логике данная процедура и не должна возвращать ничего. И при импорте указан тип возвращаемого значения `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Победить баг без костылей не удалось. Entity Framework настойчиво желает, чтоб хранимая процедура возвращала значение. Ок, пусть будет так. Добавил фиктивный выходной параметр...